# Javascript get id from element and then use it

Tags: javascript, dom

Can you help me with this problem? I can't use return x value for my other function. I want when I click on some element, then script load ID of clicked element and then change color of element with this ID.
Is there some better solution for my problem? (in pure JS, not in Jquery)
Thanks.

```
<p id="1">foo</p>
<p id="2">bar</p>
<p id="3">baz</p>




<script>

  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    x=e.target.id;
return x


  });

  document.getElementById(x).onclick = 


    function(x) {

    if (document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor !== 'yellow') {
      document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
    else {
     document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: You must use only one block

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below.

```
<p id="1">foo</p>
<p id="2">bar</p>
<p id="3">baz</p>
```

```
   document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       x=e.target.id;

       function() {
           var bgColor = document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor;
           if (bgColor !== 'yellow')    {
               bgColor = 'yellow';
           }
           else {
                bgColor = 'red';
           }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can anyone format my code ?? I am on mobile app and not able to format

Comment: What do you mean format? But this code dont work. this second function cant get this x value from first function

Comment: I updated my answer. Remove the `x` from the `function`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i find solution on my problem.
The solution was put all my script in one function and than evrything work.
I learning JS about 1 mount and now I have made one simple LIGHTS OFF game.
Now I nedd some function that check all cells color and alert end of game, but i cant answer a new question because by question is not voted well, and i dont know why.

Here is the example of my code:

```js
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var x = e.target.id



  var up    = ((Math.floor(x.charAt(0))-1).toString()).concat(x.charAt(1));
  var down  = ((Math.floor(x.charAt(0))+1).toString()).concat(x.charAt(1));
  var left  = (x.charAt(0)).concat((Math.floor(x.charAt(1))-1).toString());
  var right = (x.charAt(0)).concat((Math.floor(x.charAt(1))+1).toString());

    
   
    if( document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor == ''){document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor = 'black';}
    else{document.getElementById(x).style.backgroundColor ='';}

    if(document.getElementById(up)!=null){
    if( document.getElementById(up).style.backgroundColor == ''){document.getElementById(up).style.backgroundColor = 'black';}
    else{document.getElementById(up).style.backgroundColor ='';}}

    if(document.getElementById(down)!=null){
    if( document.getElementById(down).style.backgroundColor == ''){document.getElementById(down).style.backgroundColor = 'black';}
    else{document.getElementById(down).style.backgroundColor ='';}}
    
    if(document.getElementById(left)!=null){
    if( document.getElementById(left).style.backgroundColor == ''){document.getElementById(left).style.backgroundColor = 'black';}
    else{document.getElementById(left).style.backgroundColor ='';}}
    
    if(document.getElementById(right)!=null){
    if( document.getElementById(right).style.backgroundColor == ''){document.getElementById(right).style.backgroundColor = 'black';}
    else{document.getElementById(right).style.backgroundColor ='';}}


   // var all = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  //  var i;
  //  for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  //   all[i].style.backgroundColor!=='yellow';
  //    alert('a')
   //   break}

  })
```

```css
td  {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td id='11'></td>
  <td id='12'></td>
  <td id='13'></td>
  <td id='14'></td>
  <td id='15'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id='21'></td>
  <td id='22'></td>
  <td id='23'></td>
  <td id='24'></td>
  <td id='25'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id='31'></td>
  <td id='32'></td>
  <td id='33'></td>
  <td id='34'></td>
  <td id='35'></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='41'></td>
    <td id='42'></td>
    <td id='43'></td>
    <td id='44'></td>
    <td id='45'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='51'></td>
    <td id='52'></td>
    <td id='53'></td>
    <td id='54'></td>
    <td id='55'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```